# which App Server supports both AdoptOpenJdk11.0.3 and RedHat Open jdk 11.0.3?

Tags: redhat-openjdk, adoptopenjdk

I wanted to know that which Server supports both AdoptOpenJdk 11.0.3 and RedHat Open jdk 11.0.3.  I have tried to search on google but was not able to find anything, It will be helpfull if anybody can tell me.

Answer (score 0):

For deployment, I used tomcat 9.0.7 for adoptjk11 compiled ear and  jboss 7.2 for redhtjdk 11 compiled ear.